# How to input mask in RsForms?

Tags: jquery, rsform

How to create a input Mask with jQuery in RSForms?
I have try all documentation from RSJoomla without success:

https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/form-fields/textbox.html

My question is in "Input Mask" no "Validation field"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED for all Forms!!!

1. Create file like /includes/jquery.maskedinput.js
2. Copy and paste this code from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js
3. Propably you have a jQuery library running in your Joomla;
4. Add in index.php after tag body;

```
src="includes/js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){
$("#telefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9",{placeholder:" "}); //Where #telefone = #ID Name form label
$("#celular").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9",{placeholder:" "}); //Where #celular = #ID Name form label
});
```

4. Now, all your forms with elements "#telefone" and "#celular" will be masked!

You can see complete documentation for this jQuery Masked Input in:
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

If you dont want edit your index.php file you can add this code in each form you need Masked:

Components >> RSForm >> Edit your form >>

Tab Proporties >> Tab Script >>

Paste in Java Script field without "---". I put this --- for simple copy and paste for others users.

```
<---script src="includes/js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"><---/script>

<---script>
jQuery(function($){

   $("#telefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9",{placeholder:" "}); //Where #telefone = #ID Name form label
   $("#celular").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9",{placeholder:" "});
   $("#phone_1_field").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9",{placeholder:" "});
   $("#phone_2_field").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9",{placeholder:" "});
   $("#fax_field").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9",{placeholder:" "});
   $("#zip_field").mask("99999-999",{placeholder:" "});

});
<---/script>
```